# How to print out the indexes in a list with repetitive elements

Tags: python, list, indexing

I want to create a function where it has a list and a threshold in the parameter.
This function will return a list of the int indexes for those in the values in the list that are bigger than the previous value by the threshold or more.

So far, I created:

```
def bigger(lst, number):
    x = []
    for a, prev in zip(lst[1:], number):
        diff = a - prev
       if diff >= 2:
            x.append(a)
    print(x)

bigger([0,1,-1,3,7,4,5,3,2,4,8],2)
```

This will print out the list of numbers that meet the following criteria, but I would like to print the list of indexes. So it SHOULD print out [3, 4, 9, 10] (the indexes) but it prints out [3, 7, 4, 8]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `zip` and `enumerate`, `enumerate` would return the indexes as well as items:

```
def solve(lis, num):
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(lis, lis[1:]), 1):
        if y - x >= num:
            yield i

print list(solve([0,1,-1,3,7,4,5,3,2,4,8], 2))
#[3, 4, 9, 10]
```

If you want to support generators as well, then:

```
from itertools import tee, izip
def solve(lis, num):
    it1, it2 = tee(lis, 2)
    next(it2)  #drop first item
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(izip(it1, it2), 1):
        print x, y
        if y - x >= num:
            yield i

print list(solve((x for x in [0,1,-1,3,7,4,5,3,2,4,8]), 2))
#[3, 4, 9, 10]
```

Comment: this is way too complicated, why use a `zip` inside `enumerate`?

Comment: what if i wanted to iterate over a generator instead of a list? would this still work?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac this is exactly complicated enough, and a pretty idiomatic way to iterate over adjacent pairs.

Comment: @Lalala no: `[1:]` doesn't work on generator iterators, and this code tries to read the iterable twice.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac yes?  though other things are also iteration

Comment: how would i change this so it can run for both lists and a generator?

Comment: @hcwhsa might as well use `izip` while you're at it  :)

Answer (score 2):

hint, you can use `list.index(element, [start,[end]])` to achieve this

@Games Brainiac, this is how to use list.index() to return position for a list of element

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,7,8]
b = [2,5,6]
def findItem(a,b):
    index = []
    for item in b:
        start = -1
        while True:
            try:
                start = a.index(item, start+1)
                index.append(start)
            except ValueError:
                break;
    return index
print findItem(a,b)
```

in my case, the result is:

```
[1, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

pls next time, think twice to downvote

Comment: yes i tried this but since the list has repetitive elements it does not work.

Comment: nvm. What i mean is that ls.index(element, [start,[end]]) from this you can return multiple by using a loop to update start

Comment: I've improved your indentation and exception handling, but it still doesn't work. Try `b = [1,2,5,6]` and check the result.

Comment: sorry for that, in that case, start should be -1 at the first place.

Comment: the problem is because if start=0 at the first place, it will not look for the first item in the list. Thx for pointing out my fault.

Answer (score 0):

```
def bigger(l, num):
    _ret = []
    for i, var in enumerate(l[1:], start=1):
        if var - l[i - 1] >= num:
            _ret.append(i)

    return _ret
```

Take a look at the above code, it does what you expect it to do. Working [example](http://ideone.com/R2B4Lq). The above, but in list comprehension:

```
def bigger(l, num):
    return [i for i, var in enumerate(l[1:], start=1) if var - l[i - 1] >= num]
```

You can also make a generator from this:

```
def bigger(l, num):
    for i, var in enumerate(l[1:], start=1):
        if var - l[i - 1] >= num:
            yield i
```

Working [example](http://ideone.com/Jep4QD).